# A column named 'Date' and EF Core 7 migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

On our entity has this property:

```cs
public DateTime Date { get; init; }
```

We then renamed that to:

```cs
public DateTime DateUTC { get; init; }
```

In the `Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` method, we have:

```cs
migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
  name: "Date",
  table: "VirtualAccountStatus",
  newName: "DateUTC");
```

The migration fails to run and gives the following exception:

> Applying migration '20220422111129_Rename_VirtualAccountDateField'. Failed executing DbCommand (67ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] EXEC sp_rename N'[VirtualAccountStatus].[''Date'']', N'DateUTC', N'COLUMN'; Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

```
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs:line 2010
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlInternalConnection.cs:line 770
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 1421
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs:line 2637
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs:line 3502
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName) in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs:line 1667
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in /_/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs:line 1213
```

I think it is because EF Core 7 doesn't like the fact that we had a column named `Date` (reserved keyword maybe?)

How can I overcome this so that I rename the field and get the migrations happy?

Comment: Try to correct this SQL `sp_rename N'[VirtualAccountStatus].[''Date'']', N'DateUTC', N'COLUMN';` and put it in migration as raw SQL.

Comment: What happens if you try `migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "[Date]", table: "VirtualAccountStatus", newName: "DateUTC")`?

Comment: DateUTC sounds like it could be some sort of a reserved name, have you tried temporarily renaming it to something definitely unique to rule that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, might change migration to:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("EXEC sp_rename N'[VirtualAccountStatus].[Date]', N'DateUTC', N'COLUMN';");
```